# Select from database with dynamic where condition

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

In this case, I made ​​a row with jquery additional mechanism to obtain the parameters that I will use in data search.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    DataProvide();
    ManipulationHere();

    $('table').delegate('input[type=text].onlyDate', 'focusin', function(event) {
        $(this).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '1972:2020',
        });
    });

    $('table').delegate('input[type=text].onlyMonth', 'focusin', function(event) {
        $(this).monthpicker();
    });

}); //Tutup Document Ready


function ManipulationHere(){

var count = 1;
$(".button").click(function(){
    count += 1;
    var $row = $('<tr>' 
    + '<td>' + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + '<input id="data2_' + count + '" type="text" name="data2_' + count + '" class="data2" />' + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + '<input id="rows_' + count + '" name="rows[]" value="'+ count +'" type="hidden">'
        + '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a>' + '</td>'
    + '</tr>').appendTo("#customFields");
    var copyData = $("#data1_1").clone();
    var repID = copyData.attr('id', 'data1_' + count + '');
    var repName = copyData.attr('name', 'data1_' + count + '');

    $row.find('td:first').append(repID)
    var check = $row.find('td:first').html();
    var get = $(check).attr('id')
});

    $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        count -= 1;
    });

    $("#customFields").on('change', '.tabelBaru', function() {

        var validator = $("#signupForm").validate();
        validator.resetForm();

        var $this = $(this),
        nilai = $this.val();
        console.log(nilai);

        if(nilai=='gender'){
            $this.closest("tr").find(".data2").replaceWith(
                '<select name="data2_' + count + '" class="data2">'
                    + '<option value="man" selected >Man</option>'
                    + '<option value="woman">Woman</option>'
                + '</select>'
            )
        }
        else if(nilai=='religion'){
            $this.closest("tr").find(".data2").replaceWith(
                '<select name="data2[]" class="data2">'
                    + '<option value="protestan" selected >Protestan</option>'
                    + '<option value="khatolik">Khatolik</option>'
                    + '<option value="islam">Islam</option>'
                    + '<option value="budha">Budha</option>'
                    + '<option value="hindu">Hindu</option>'
                + '</select>'
            )
        }
        else if(nilai=='blood'){
            $this.closest("tr").find(".data2").replaceWith(
                '<select name="data2_' + count + '" class="data2">'
                    + '<option value="gol_a" selected >A</option>'
                    + '<option value="gol_b">B</option>'
                    + '<option value="gol_ab">AB</option>'
                    + '<option value="gol_o">O</option>'
                + '</select>'
            )
        }
        else if(nilai=='birth_date'){
            $this.closest("tr").find(".data2").replaceWith(
                '<input type="text" id="data2_' + count + '" name="data2_' + count + '" value="" placeholder="Date Format" class="onlyDate"/>'
            )
        }
        else if(nilai=='start_date'){
            $this.closest("tr").find(".data2").replaceWith(
                '<input type="text" id="data2_' + count + '" name="data2_' + count + '" value="" placeholder="Date Format" class="onlyDate"/>'
            )
        }
        else if(nilai=='end_date'){
            $this.closest("tr").find(".data2").replaceWith(
                '<input type="text" id="data2_' + count + '" name="data2_' + count + '" value="" placeholder="Date Format" class="onlyDate"/>'
            )
        }
        else if(nilai=='join_date'){
            $this.closest("tr").find(".data2").replaceWith(
                '<input type="text" id="data2_' + count + '" name="data2_' + count + '" value="" placeholder="Date Format" class="onlyDate"/>'
            )
        }
        else if(nilai=='los_month'){
            $this.closest("tr").find(".data2").replaceWith(
                '<input type="text" id="data2_' + count + '" name="data2_' + count + '" value="" placeholder="Month Format" class="onlyMonth"/>'
            )
        }
        else{
            $this.closest("tr").find(".onlyDate").replaceWith(
                '<input type="text" id="data2_' + count + '" name="data2_' + count + '" value="" class="data2"/>'
            )
        }

    });
}


function DataProvide(){
    selectValues = { 
        "pilih"         : "-Pilih-",
        "id"            : "ID",
        "emp_name"      : "Employee Name",
        "photo_path"    : "Photo Path",
        "emp_id"        : "Employee ID",
        "birth_place"   : "Birth Place",
        "birth_date"    : "Birth Date",
        "age"           : "Age",
        "gender"        : "Gender",
        "religion"      : "Religion",
    };

    $.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {   
         $('#data1_1')
             .append($("<option></option>")
             .attr("value",key)
             .text(value)); 
    }); 
}
```

The results of the above process, I have a line that will be used as a parameter.

For example, when a row is added :
[image: Step 1]

I want to create query generated after the SAVE process is :

```
SELECT * from my_table_name WHERE id='123'
```

If I add one more line parameters with example :
[image: Step 2]

I want to create query generated after the SAVE process is :

```
SELECT * from my_table_name WHERE id='123' and employee_name='Testing'
```

And if I want to add another parameter search by adding a third line :
[image: Step 3]

I want to query is generated after clicking the button in the process is :

```
SELECT * from my_table_name WHERE id='123' and employee_name='Testing' and employee_id='111'
```

I have made ​​a function to try to read the data from the form POST results like this :

```
    $Query = "SELECT * from my_table_name WHERE ....... << from looping"
    foreach ($_POST['rows'] as $key => $count ){
            $Data1  = $_POST['data1_'.$count];
            $Data2  = $_POST['data2_'.$count];
            echo $Data1." >> ".$Data2;
            echo "<br>";
    }
```

How do I get the data key and value from the POST results for later input into my query?

Comment: What is the actual output you get from the `echo $Data1. " >> " . $Data2;`?

Comment: @JustinWood As in my example : id >> 123
emp_name >> Testing
emp_id >> 111   It is only as an example to me see if I get the data successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, you just need to change your loop a little bit.

```
$query = "SELECT * from my_table_name WHERE ";

$first = true;

foreach ($_POST['rows'] as $key => $count ) {
    $field = $_POST['data1_' . $count];
    $value = $_POST['data2_' . $count];

    if ($first) {
        $query .= $field . " = '" . $value . "'";
        $first = false;
    } else {
        $query .= " AND " . $field . " = '" . $value . "'";
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, this will only work if you submit at least one item to be queried against.

This also assumes that what you get back from `$field` is the name of the field in the database.

As an additional exercise, I strongly suggest that you look to see if you database implementation can use prepared statements. They are significantly more secure.

Comment: Thanks justin...But how do I construct a query that will be called to the database? I have tried and always failed ... I'm using Yii (DAO) to conduct this search

Comment: @JustinWood don't you need to put an "AND" in the query when there are more than one where statement. You cannot just have `id='123' employee_name='Testing'` you need an `AND` between those.

Comment: @amaster507 Yes, u'r correct. There is no command AND to combine the parameters

Comment: @amaster507 wow, I can't believe I forgot that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @BerthoJoris I am unsure what you mean. The query is being constructed there. Are you asking how to actually execute said query?